# Does TinyMCE have any function to convert HTML to Plain text?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tinymce

Does TinyMCE have any function to convert HTML to Plain text?
I want to convert HTML to plain text outside the rich text editor, Like the function in Draft JS (htmlToDraft(html)), I'm working on react JS, I don't want to use a package just for converting HTML to Plain text, if there's any fucnction provided by TinyMCE itself, it would be useful. If anyone knows any idea or any workaround for this, Please help me. I'm a bit inexperienced. :)